# Blender Viewport Shading (A method of displaying/shading objects in 3D view: Material Preview) problem

Tags: 3d, rendering, textures, blender, texturing

I have the problem in Blender 2.9. When I enable Viewport Shading (A method of displaying/shading objects in 3D view: Material Preview), the object on the screen becomes dark and the light doesn't work. Could you please tell me what should I do to fix the problem?

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW2Ze.jpg)

[How it should looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWOuF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem with the equipment or with the scene settings. Try opening blender through CMD and see if there is an error message. You can also attach the scene file in question, and technical data about your computer